# Cómo comparar dos arrays en PHP?

Tags: php, array

Cordial saludo comunidad.
Les explico mi problema. Tengo dos arreglos:

```
$dirTelefonico = [
                ['Nombre' => 'Jose', 'Direccion' => 'Calle 45 # 52-89', 'Telefono' => '3126553213', 'Fecha' => '24/06/1992', 'color_favorito' => 'rojo'],
                ['Nombre' => 'Pedro', 'Direccion' => 'Cra 77 # 45-89', 'Telefono' => '3007456254', 'Fecha' => '30/05/1988', 'color_favorito' => 'azul'],
                ['Nombre' => 'Pablo', 'Direccion' => 'Calle 72 #23-96', 'Telefono' => '3207849863', 'Fecha' => '12/03/1991', 'color_favorito' => 'verde']
            ];

$significado_color = [
                ['color' => 'azul', 'significado' => 'constancia,autoridad y confianza'],
                ['color' => 'verde', 'significado' => 'celos,envidia,ecologia,salud'],
                ['color' => 'amarillo', 'significado' => 'energia,resplandor,brillantez']
            ];
```

Mientras los imprimo(que lo hago con dos foreach) necesito comparar el valor del índice de "color_favorito" del primer arreglo con el de "color" del segundo arreglo y si el color se encuentra en el segundo arreglo imprima su significado, sino imprima que no se encuentra.Este es el codigo que "mejor" me ha funcionado, pero me sale error de undefined offset y además me imprime el resultado por cada valor de indice del primer arreglo. Aquí el código.

```
$tamanio = count($significado_color);
            //echo $tamanio."<br>";
            foreach ($dirTelefonico as $key => $value) {
                ?>
                <!---<tr>-->
                    <?php
                    $i = 0;

                    foreach ($value as $value) {
                        $j = 0;
                        $temp = "No se encuentra el significado";
                        while ($j < $tamanio) {
                            if ($dirTelefonico[$i]['color_favorito'] === $significado_color[$j]['color']) {
                                //echo $v . $dirTelefonico[$i]['color_favorito'];
                                $temp = $significado_color[$j]['significado'];
                                break;
                            } else {
                                $j++;
                            }
                        }
                        echo $value.$temp;
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
```

Por favor necesito de su ayuda. Estaré muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con `foreach` y con `if`, por favor visualiza el siguiente código:

```
$dirTelefonico = [
                ['Nombre' => 'Jose', 'Direccion' => 'Calle 45 # 52-89', 'Telefono' => '3126553213', 'Fecha' => '24/06/1992', 'color_favorito' => 'rojo'],
                ['Nombre' => 'Pedro', 'Direccion' => 'Cra 77 # 45-89', 'Telefono' => '3007456254', 'Fecha' => '30/05/1988', 'color_favorito' => 'azul'],
                ['Nombre' => 'Pablo', 'Direccion' => 'Calle 72 #23-96', 'Telefono' => '3207849863', 'Fecha' => '12/03/1991', 'color_favorito' => 'verde']
            ];

$significado_color = [
                ['color' => 'azul', 'significado' => 'constancia,autoridad y confianza'],
                ['color' => 'verde', 'significado' => 'celos,envidia,ecologia,salud'],
                ['color' => 'amarillo', 'significado' => 'energia,resplandor,brillantez']
            ];

foreach($dirTelefonico as $key1){
   foreach($significado_color as $key2){
      if($key1['color_favorito'] == $key2['color']){
        echo $key2['significado']."<br>";
      }else{ echo "no se encuentra el significado!<br>";}
   }
}
```

Prueba este código, y cuéntanos como te va

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me fue de mucha ayuda, no tenía en cuenta que lo que debía hacer era recorrer un array dentro de otro y comparar los valores. Aunque le hice una pequeña modificación para que me imprimiera los demas valores del array del directorio telefonico.

Comment: Sin embargo, te invito a que revises las otras respuestas, ya que tienen mejores prácticas que la solución que yo te mostré ;) no es muy bueno tener un ciclo adentro de otro ciclo iterativo.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías resolverlo usando [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php) y [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-walk.php) de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
$dirTelefonico = [
    ['Nombre' => 'Jose', 'Direccion' => 'Calle 45 # 52-89', 'Telefono' => '3126553213', 'Fecha' => '24/06/1992', 'color_favorito' => 'rojo'],
    ['Nombre' => 'Pedro', 'Direccion' => 'Cra 77 # 45-89', 'Telefono' => '3007456254', 'Fecha' => '30/05/1988', 'color_favorito' => 'azul'],
    ['Nombre' => 'Pablo', 'Direccion' => 'Calle 72 #23-96', 'Telefono' => '3207849863', 'Fecha' => '12/03/1991', 'color_favorito' => 'verde']
];

$significado_color = [
    ['color' => 'azul', 'significado' => 'constancia,autoridad y confianza'],
    ['color' => 'verde', 'significado' => 'celos,envidia,ecologia,salud'],
    ['color' => 'amarillo', 'significado' => 'energia,resplandor,brillantez']
];

// Creamos un arreglo donde la clave son los colores y el valor el significado
$colorHash = array_column($significado_color, 'significado', 'color');

// A cada persona en el arreglo le agregamos "color_significado"
array_walk($dirTelefonico, function(&$persona) use ($colorHash) {
    $color = $persona['color_favorito'];
    $persona['color_significado'] = isset($colorHash[$color]) ? $colorHash[$color] : 'No se encuentra el significado';
});

echo json_encode($dirTelefonico, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

El resultado:

```
[
    {
        "Nombre": "Jose",
        "Direccion": "Calle 45 # 52-89",
        "Telefono": "3126553213",
        "Fecha": "24\/06\/1992",
        "color_favorito": "rojo",
        "color_significado": "No se encuentra el significado"
    },
    {
        "Nombre": "Pedro",
        "Direccion": "Cra 77 # 45-89",
        "Telefono": "3007456254",
        "Fecha": "30\/05\/1988",
        "color_favorito": "azul",
        "color_significado": "constancia,autoridad y confianza"
    },
    {
        "Nombre": "Pablo",
        "Direccion": "Calle 72 #23-96",
        "Telefono": "3207849863",
        "Fecha": "12\/03\/1991",
        "color_favorito": "verde",
        "color_significado": "celos,envidia,ecologia,salud"
    }
]
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/937befeca1cee6b845ccca1319447387dc8f2ef9)</kbd>

Comment: Excelente solución,  ¿podría usarse para comparar dos columnas?

Comment: Hola Daniel, probablemente si, pero para "comparar" es muy probable que exista una mejor solución.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ayudarte de [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php) y [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php) para facilitar las cosas, por ejemplo con los arrays que tienes pues hacer así:

```
<?php

$dirTelefonico = [
                ['Nombre' => 'Jose', 'Direccion' => 'Calle 45 # 52-89', 'Telefono' => '3126553213', 'Fecha' => '24/06/1992', 'color_favorito' => 'rojo'],
                ['Nombre' => 'Pedro', 'Direccion' => 'Cra 77 # 45-89', 'Telefono' => '3007456254', 'Fecha' => '30/05/1988', 'color_favorito' => 'azul'],
                ['Nombre' => 'Pablo', 'Direccion' => 'Calle 72 #23-96', 'Telefono' => '3207849863', 'Fecha' => '12/03/1991', 'color_favorito' => 'verde']
            ];

$significado_color = [
                ['color' => 'azul', 'significado' => 'constancia,autoridad y confianza'],
                ['color' => 'verde', 'significado' => 'celos,envidia,ecologia,salud'],
                ['color' => 'amarillo', 'significado' => 'energia,resplandor,brillantez']
            ];

// Optenemos un array con los colores
$colores = array_column($significado_color, 'color');

// Recorremos dirTelefonico
foreach ($dirTelefonico as $dir) {
    // Buscamos si esiste el color en los colores
    // si existe array_search nos devuelve la key que la asignamos a $key en el mismo if
    // si no existe nos retornara false y saltara el else
    if($key = array_search($dir['color_favorito'], $colores)) {
        // Utilizamos la $key devuelta por array_search para imprimir el significado 
        echo $dir['color_favorito'] . ': ' . $significado_color[$key]['significado'];
    } else {
        echo 'No se ha encontrado el color: ' . $dir['color_favorito'];
    }
    // Agremamos un <br> para formatear el resultado
    echo '<br>';
}

?>
```

Resultado:

```
No se ha encontrado el color: rojo
No se ha encontrado el color: azul
verde: celos,envidia,ecologia,salud
```